# What does the blue ring in Pangu Lagoon do?

Tags: freedom-planet

In Stage 7 (Pangu Lagoon) I came across a blue ring. Jumping through the ring made a blue star start circling around me. What does the blue ring do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the Freedom Planet Wiki](https://freedomplanet.fandom.com/wiki/Pangu_Lagoon#Time_Gates_&_Dragon_Stars), the blue rings are Time Gates that enhance Lilac's Hair Whip attack and Dragon Boost.

> Time Gates are blue orbs that make up rings, and are exclusive to this Stage. Passing through one will spawn a Dragon Star that will orbit Lilac until it is used up. With a Dragon Star, **Lilac's standard Hair Whip attack will be able to fire a short-range projectile** that looks similar to Neera Li's Ice Lasso, but without the freezing effect. **It will also super-charge Lilac's Dragon Boost, turning it into the Super Dragon Boost, even enabling her to use a standard Dragon Boost afterwards.**

[image: Super Dragon Boost in action]

<sub>Gif from [Freedom Planet - Part 22 - Pangu Lagoon 1 (5:40) by Overhazard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ilLrB7rri0)</sub>